# in didselect row my first row returnig label text instead of my custom label text

Tags: uitableview, uilabel, didselectrowatindexpath

here i have a table view where i'm adding custom label which stores some
quiz ids from array 
where cell.textlabel.text stores quiz names from array

problem:
when i'm selecting first row in didselectRowAtIndexPath
it returns cell.textlabel.tex but for second row it is returning correct value that is 
quiz ids

here is code

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellId";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

}
cell.textLabel.text = [quizname objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

UILabel *lbl = [[UILabel alloc]init];
lbl.tag=indexPath.row;
[cell addSubview:lbl];
lbl.text = [quizIds objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

return cell;
}
```

in did selectrow

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
UILabel *label = (UILabel *) [cell viewWithTag:indexPath.row];
NSString *qid =label.text;
NSLog(@"%@",qid);

}
```

i'm getting quid is equal to cell.texlabel.text for firsr row but not in others rows 
they are getting quiz ids perfectly

any help most valueble for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using customTableViewCell & add your label inside the customCell. Adding UILabel inside cellForRowAtIndexPath is not a good approach.

Comment: nice answer but what is error in cellforRowatIndexpath

Comment: Use breakpoint & check in cellForRowAtIndexPath. Add conditions like. if (indexPath == 0){ cell.textLabel.text = [yourArray objectAtIndex: 0];} else{cell.textLabel.text = [yourArray objectAtIndex:1]}. And use breakpoint in didSelectRowAtIndexPath also & check whether it is throwing correct value or not.

Comment: You are getting the issue after selecting the row?